# read .conf file python ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

I need to read config.conf file in Python using ConfigParser. The thing I'm trying to do is, club `$dataDir` variable with a fileName and can't get expected output as given below.

config.conf

```
[dir]
dataDir = /home/srujan/Documents/r2d2/data-cut/SLIM/postcut

[files]
current_materiel = ${{dataDir}} + /20201209-rtvm_api_current_materiel_not_filtered_OS.csv
```

Expected output:

```
/home/srujan/Documents/r2d2/data-cut/SLIM/postcut/20201209-rtvm_api_current_materiel_not_filtered_OS.csv
```

Debug results - I get as a text instead of dataDir path.
${{dataDir}} + /20201209-rtvm_api_current_materiel_not_filtered_OS.csv

Comment: What do you get instead of the expected output? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values.

The default interpolation only allows use of variables from the same section with `%(varname)` syntax. If you want variables to persist across multiple sections, you need to use the extended interpolation

```
parser = configparser.ConfigParser(..., interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
```

Extended interpolation uses `${section:option}` to denote a value from a foreign section.